# Formato de fecha en visual foxpro

Tags: foxpro

Hola de antemano les agradezco su apoyo, les platico el problema, tengo una base de datos en visual foxpro (archivos .dbf) de la cual necesito por medio de consultas alimentar una base de datos en mysql. El problema es con los campos de fecha ya que no eh encontrado como convertir en visual foxpro al formato YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS que es el formato que acepta mysql

Comment: de dbf a MySql, correcto? lo estás llenando directamente, o estás utilizando algún lenguaje de por medio para el traspaso? que haz intentado? he peleado con eso antes pero necesito ver que tienes de referencia

Comment: a falta de respuesta, lo que yo he hecho para eso, es hacer consultas sql al dbf, convirtiendo los datetime a varchar, reordenarlos separando la cadena y poniéndolos en el orden adecuado, para después ese varchar, transformarlo a datetime. Es un lío, pero con legado es un problema gigantesco siempre.

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios, lo estoy haciendo mediante un procedure de visual foxpro. Ya intente convertirlo a un varchar y lo armo tal como lo necesito pero al momento de convertirlo de nuevo a fecha cambia el formato. De echo, haciendo muchas pruebas e detectado que la version de mysql 5.1.33-community-log si acepta el formato de fecha de visual foxpro, no sé si en las versiones mas nuevas por ejemplo la 5.1.33-community-log se pueda configurar para que tambien la acepte

Answer (score 0):

Hola buenas tardes en mi experiencia no tengo ningún problemas con el formato de fechas desde VFP hacia Mysql, no comprendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer pero si lo que necesitas hacer es consultar el campo fecha de tu DBF y agregar el registro nuevo con esta fecha no deberías tener problemas, yo guardaría el campo fecha desde tu dbf a una variable y luego enviar el campo como parametro a mysql, automaticamente mysql interpreta en que formato debe guardar la fecha. Espero haberte sido util. Saludos!